spring kafka adding -n suffix for clientId, how to remove it
With limited understanding of Spring kafka. I'm facing this problem.
As visible in the log spring is adding -1 (or -0) for client id. This is creating a problem as kafka infrastructure has name without suffix.
My Listener:
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "kafka.event.enable")
public class KafkaEventListener {
    private final KafkaEventHandler kafkaEventHandler;

    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "gc.fds.event.external.all",
            groupId = "dispute-service-app",
            clientIdPrefix = "${kafka.groupId}",
            containerFactory = "kafkaChargebackcontainerFactory")
    public void listener(List<ChargebackKafkaEvent> kafkaEventList) {
        log.info("Received {} kafka events", kafkaEventList.size());
        kafkaEventList.forEach(kafkaEventHandler::processKafkaEvent);
    }
}

My KafkaConfig:
@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<ChargebackKafkaEvent>> kafkaChargebackcontainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        log.info("Creating_KafkaListenerContainerFactory");
        var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, List<ChargebackKafkaEvent>>();
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> container.setAlwaysClientIdSuffix(false));
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(kafkaProperties));

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, List<ChargebackKafkaEvent>> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        consumerProperties.put("client.id", "dispute-service-app");
        consumerProperties.put("group.id", "dispute-service-app");
        log.info("Kafka_consumer_properties: {}", consumerProperties);
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, List<ChargebackKafkaEvent>> defaultKafkaConsumerFactory =
        new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            consumerProperties,
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new JsonDeserializer<>(List.class, false)));

        return defaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
    }
}



The logic there is like this container.setClientIdSuffix(this.concurrency > 1 || this.alwaysClientIdSuffix ? "-" + index : "");. Not clear how that index is possible for your concurrency = 1 and setAlwaysClientIdSuffix(false). I'd like to see a simple project from you where we can investigate.

I understand. but that's literally the only kafka related stuff in the project.

I understand. But still simple project to play with on our side would be great to have. This way we definitely would be on the same page. And who knows, your sample might help to spot a bug and lead to a fix to make the whole community to benefit from your contribution.

Hi I created a mini project at https://github.com/ajeetvi/kafkatest   running the producer app shows the log client.id with suffix -0
Please help

Hold on. Producer? You showed config and logs for consumer, but now you say me to try the producer app from your sample.

SpringBootConsumerApplication is also there. But I got this working actually. now I have client.id without suffix. Thanks for your idea of minified project.

Great! Feel free to mention that as an answer to your own question.

Please see the commits in this repo for answer.
https://github.com/ajeetvi/kafkatest
